# Is it possible to use EaselJS (CreateJS) with TypeScript using parceljs?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, createjs, easeljs, parceljs

I'm trying to make a game with EaselJS, and since it's [current year], I'm using TypeScript. There are *"official"* types that I'm using from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/createjs), but I can't get it working together with parceljs. If I import the types, parcel fails. If I import without types, parcel is happy (and my build works), but I've got no types in VS Code.

Here's my import, which works for the parcel build:

```
import * as createjs from '@createjs/easeljs';
```

VS Code throws an info warning on this line stating `Could not find a declaration file for module '@createjs/easeljs'.`, and the types don't work.

Here's an import that makes VS Code happy, but parcel sad:

```
import 'createjs';
```

Now the types for EaselJS work in VS Code, but the parcel build fails with `src/main.ts:3:8: Cannot resolve dependency 'createjs'`. Not cool!

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "corona-coaster",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-only",
  "dependencies": {
    "@createjs/easeljs": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "createjs": "^1.0.1",
    "sty": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.0",
    "@types/createjs": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/easeljs": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.4",
    "@types/tweenjs": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html --public-url ./",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/testSetup.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

The GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/akc8012/corona-coaster). I cannot switch to webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Use the [createjs-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs-module) package instead, and use this as your import statement:

```
import * as createjs from 'createjs-module';
```

Congrats! The struggle is now over. No need to do anything special in the `tsconfig`, and no need to include types yourself - they are included in `createjs-module`. Neat!

Credit goes to [this comment](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/796#issuecomment-360574678).

Comment: Actually a lot of things in easeljs don't work with the module you posted. Example, easeljs 1.0.0 has no bugs with Ticker and Stage updates, however about module is using some updated version and is a lot buggy as well

Answer (score 0):

For some supply, I find something exciting work these days.
Now the @thegraid/createjs-module is updated to createjs 1.0.0, which solve a lot of problems
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thegraid/createjs-module

```
npm install --save @types/createjs
npm install --save @thegraid/createjs-module
import * as createjs from '@thegraid/createjs-module';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).